# Easiest way to parse HTML in C++

Tags: html, c++, regex, c++11

I'm using curl to get an HTML document. From this document, I want to get the name & value of any input field.

However, after many tries, my C++ regex still doesn't work and I'm starting to loose hope.

I'm using the default [c++11 regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) which use the [ECMAScript syntax](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/)

Here's my code

```
void    regexFind(std::string &str)
{
  std::string   regex = "value=\"(.*)\"";
  std::smatch   m;
  std::regex    e(regex);

  if (std::regex_search(str, m, e))
    {
      std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
    }
  else
     std::cout << "No match" << std::endl;
}

void    htmlRegexTest()
{
  std::string   str;

  str = "<div><input name=\"somteTest\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /></div>";
  regexFind(str);
}
```

So basically, I've tried many many regexp but couldn't match anything.

I'm not sure that regexp is the better solution for this problem so if you have a better solution than regex it would be also great.

Thanks in advance for your help.

### -- Edit --

Okay, so it seems that using regex to parse HTML is a bad solution. So change my question a little, what is the best solution (aka easiest) to parse HTML in c++ ?

Comment: "I know, I'll use regex *and* C++".  Now you have *three* problems.

Comment: `value=\"(.*)\"` should be `value=\"(.*?)\"`

Comment: Parsing HTML using regex is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: @vks value=\"(.*?)\" doesn't work either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well I know it's probably not the best solution so if you have another suggestion I would gladly try it

Comment: Use an HTML parser, a tool specifically designed to do what you want.